# DIsable input class for calender view in html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to put a date picker in my code,

here is the code,

The problem is i do not want them to select any date other than calender date. How can i disable the ability to type inside the

```
<div class="form-group clearfix">
  <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Date Sold</label>
  <div class="col-lg-8">
    <input type="text" id="calendar" name="date" value="" class="validate[required] form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd">
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$("#calendar").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',           
  minDate: new Date(<?php echo $year;?>,<?php echo $month -1;?>,<?php echo $day; ?>)
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `disabled` or `readonly` attributes to avoid manual entry in text, as shown below

```
<input type="text" id="calendar" 
       name="date" value="" 
       class="validate[required] form-control" 
       placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" readonly>
```

or

```
<input type="text" id="calendar" 
       name="date" value="" 
       class="validate[required] form-control" 
       placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" disabled>
```

Answer (score 0):

or jquery 1.6+:

```
$("input").prop('disabled', true);
```

jquery 1.5:

```
$("input").attr('disabled','disabled');
```